# MOD 11 Gun doesn't show up

Tags: battlefield-3

I have various guns for recon.  When I go to my soldier it shows up.  When I go use recon most of the time it doesn't show up to be able to use along with the other guns.

Anyone help? Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are on the USA side, because it is a US specific gun. Or, it could be a rare glitch that happens to me with the MP-443, where the gun disappears from the selection. If that's the case then just reboot the game and see if it appears.

Comment: But you can unlock it with RU.

Comment: It is the last unlock for the Recon class. It will not show up when playing as RU until you score 195000 as the Recon class. If they're relatively new to BF3, they won't have it as RU

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent glitch that is sometimes keeping exp from being saved and weapons from appearing even after you unlock them.This glitch is getting patched soon

this is what the developers have on this glitch

http://www.computerandvideogames.com/350208/battlefield-3-stat-freeze-glitch-blamed-on-famas/